Amazon cognito in .NET 4.7.2
I have a requirement posting here hoping someone could help. I might sound basic, as I'm new to these concept.
I have a windows.NET application 4.7.2 which needs to consume soap service. The soap service is in AWS behind API Gateway. API Gateway is integrated with Amazon Cognito service to provide client credential grant Oauth 2.0.
So, I have Auth URL to request for token, client id and secret. I need to send that token in a header to soap service. Can someone guide me with examples how to get the token using Auth URL, client id and secret. I prefer to use AmazonCognitoIdentityProvider. Thanks!

Refer to the README - https://github.com/ankushjain358/OAuth2.ClientCredentials
